# Why does Shingo wear a towel like a girl?

Tags: sailor-moon

About six minutes into S1E40 of *Sailor Moon*, Usagi wants her younger brother Shingo to join the family in the hot spring, but he is ashamed and wears a towel. The weird part is that it covers his non-existent breasts, since he is a boy.

[image: screenshots]

Why would a boy cover himself to that extent? At first, I thought that I had misunderstood something and that the boy actually is Sailor Moon's female friend or something, but I double-checked, and it really is her brother.

Is this yet another "strange Japanese thing"?

Comment: Surely the obvious explanation is that that's just how big the towel is? I'm a boy (well, man), and the towels in my house are large enough to cover my chest, and I don't care.

Comment: [This](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11249943876) asks the exact same question. There is not really an answer, but  the asker is guessing it was simply the choice of the animators.

Comment: There was a short mention about this in [someone's episode review in Japanese](http://blog.livedoor.jp/melamine/archives/1521808.html), wondering why Shingou was behaving effeminately.